# Error in post2/implementation.cpp: 1156 with passenger 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger

I had deployed a Sinatra App using passenger gem version 3.0.19 on Ruby 1.9.2-p290 and it was working fine. When I upgraded my Ruby to 2.0.0 and passenger to 4.0.2, I am getting this line in /var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[ 2013-05-09 10:18:40.7277 6116/41715940 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1156 ]: [App 6157 stderr] 172.16.24.58 - - [09/May/2013 10:18:40] "GET / " 1146 - 0.0018
```

Any ideas what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Firstly, this is not an error but an output logged to the STDERR.
Next, this weird process fixed the problem:

1. run passenger in stand-alone mode.

   `passenger start`

2. install the apache module again

   `passenger-install-apache2-module`

3. restart httpd

   `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`